# For-loop in a list with datasets in Python

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

I have 32 datasets, with the same structure, I need to do some preparation in each one and then join them. For do the cleaning I've prepared a function and then I've tried to put that function in a loop, but it doesn't work.

Here my code

First: I imported the datasets to my environment in a list called `files`, I'm working in Google Colab.

```
import glob
import os 
os.chdir('/content')

extension = 'xls'
all_files = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]

files = []
for filename in all_files:
  data = pd.read_excel(filename, skiprows=6)
  files.append(data)
```

Second:
I did my cleaning function.

```
def data_cleaning(data):
  data = data.iloc[2:, :4]
  data = data[(data['Desglose'] != 'Localidades')]
  data = data.drop(columns='Desglose')
  data = data.rename(columns={'Total de localidades y su población1': 'poblacion'})
  data['municipio'] = data['Municipio'].str.split(' ', n = 1).str.get(-1)
  data['entidad_federativa'] = data['Entidad federativa'].str.split(' ', n = 1).str.get(-1)
  data = data.iloc[:, 2:]
  return data
```

And finally:
I'll try to make a `for` loop to repeat the cleaning process in each dataset of the list `files`.

```
files_clean = []
for i in files:
  data_clean = data_cleaning(files[i])
  files_clean.append(data_clean)
```

The error I get is:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-435517607919> in <module>()
      1 files_clean = []
      2 for i in files:
----> 3   data_clean = data_cleaning(files[i])
      4   files_clean.append(data_clean)

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not DataFram
```

I've done a similar process in `R` but I can't repeat it in `Python`. So, any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work?  You need to elaborate.  Also, you have not provided any example data to work with.

Comment: Does `data_cleaning` work with a single piece of data?

Comment: yep `data_cleaning` works with just one dataset

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: `i` in the loop isn't an index that's the item in the list. Refer to the [documentation on for-statement](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements). Replace  `data_clean = data_cleaning(files[i])` with `data_clean = data_cleaning(i)`.

Answer (score 0):

The error `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not DataFram` is raised when you try to access a list using DataFrame values instead of an integer. To solve this problem, make sure that you access a list using an index number.

A common scenario where this error is raised is when you iterate over a list and compare objects in the list. To solve this error, you can use `range()` in python for loops.

```
for i in range(len(files))
```

or else you can check the `type` of `files` and type of one object in files and make necessary changes according to that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the index. `for i in files` does not return i as an integer but as a dataframe. A possible solution to your problem will be:

```
for df in files:
  data_clean = data_cleaning(df)
  files_clean.append(data_clean)
```

or similarly

```
for i in range(len(files)):
  data_clean = data_cleaning(files[i])
  files_clean.append(data_clean)
```

or possibly

```
for i, df in enumerate(files):
  data_clean = data_cleaning(files[i])
  files_clean.append(data_clean)
```